# Is an iframe the best way to use the dynatree when retrieving results?

Tags: dynatree

I have a two column css layout.  Left container holds the dynatree.  It's pulling from a local json file.  The right side will be the content, populated by clicking on a node on the dynatree.

What I saw on the dynatree examples was the usage of an iframe with urls in the tree.

Is using the iframe the "best" way to do things?  Is this the only way to populate the content?

I'm probably being silly, but iFrames don't usually seem like a good way to go on things.  Is there a better way?  Should I be using ajax (can I?)?

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html

"Example: URL navigation and iframes"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by placing my ajax in the onactivate event of dynatree:

```
$("#response").load("myname.php?name=Johnny&dummy=" + new Date().getTime());
```

the date gettime was to defeat the ie caching problem.

Answer (score 0):

i use Div containers, with a 2 columns layout.
The tree uses ajax to load initially and the later expanded content.
When a node is activated, i reload page content and the right part is updated with data associated to the node. tree is still loaded from ajax.

You can do it this way, or load right content with ajax.

Comment: I do not understand.  If I click on a node, I want the right side populated via ajax.  Can it be done?